# CCM on Datastax Cassandra- Python 2.6 error and failure in creating local clusters

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, opscenter, ccm

I installed CCM(Cassandra Cluster Manager) on Datastax CentOS that by default creates a reference to Python 2.6 . It started off with this error: [image]

I read it's a bug and so changed { } to {0} in the necessary .py files so Python 2.6 can take correct parameters and **it did work**. However, now when I try using the same 'ccm create' command it halts for infinite time on downloading the Cassandra version as specified:
[image]

Does anybody have any solution to this? It never goes ahead. I tried redirecting it to archives and download Cassandra from there but doesn't work.

Also, DataStax OpsCentre, while creating cluster and installing it throws 'MELD error'. Little or NO help provided around this.

Please help! I have already spent a whole week after this in vain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CCM right now doesn't support python 2.6. It's only currently tested against 2.7 and 3.0 versions of python. I recommend installing python 2.7 and using that.

Comment: Thank for your reply! Could you please tell how that is done?
I checked python using 'which python' and changed it to python2.7. However, when I run 'ccm create...' command, it's still referring to python2.6 from /usr/lib/python2.6/ ......